# Edit Action is not displaying in Magento 2 Admin custom grid?

Tags: magento, magento2

I am working on a custom admin grid. Edit option for the grid row is not displaying in the Action column. Why? 
Kindly tell me where I am doing wrong here? I am new to Magento 2. 
[image]
Here is Action.php code:

```
class Action extends Column
{
    /** Url path */
    const ROW_EDIT_URL = 'grid/grid/addrow';
    /** @var UrlInterface */
    protected $_urlBuilder;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $_editUrl;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = [],
        $editUrl = self::ROW_EDIT_URL
    ) 
    {
        $this->_urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        $this->_editUrl = $editUrl;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
                $name = $this->getData('name');
                if (isset($item['entity_id'])) {
                    $item[$name]['edit'] = [
                        'href' => $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl(
                            $this->_editUrl, 
                            ['id' => $item['entity_id']]
                        ),
                        'label' => __('Edit'),
                    ];
                }
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled the module again and it worked well.